# How to send AWS Account ID of EKS cluster to Prometheus/Grafana

Tags: prometheus, amazon-eks

I have an EKS cluster in multiple AWS accounts and capturing metrics on each and sending then to a centralized Grafana. I have the grafana dashboard set up and the account info doesn't populate.
I'm installing prometheus using helm. This is my values.yaml file.

```
extraScrapeConfigs: |
  - job_name: 'prometheus-account-scraper'
    metrics_path: /metrics
    kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: pod
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_account]
        target_label: account
        action: keep
```

Below is what i see when i run `kubectl describe deployment <> -n <>`

```
Labels:                 account=12345
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 2
                        prometheus.io/path: /metrics
                        prometheus.io/scrape: true
```

Below is what i have in my grafana dashboard "variables" section
[image]

Comment: Did I get this correct: you have a Prometheus in each of the clusters, right? If so, try using external labels (put account id there, see Prometheus configuration reference https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/ )